# Override 65ch max-width in Tailwind CSS Typography

Tags: css, tailwind-css, extend, typography, prose

I am using a Jekyll template with Tailwind and Typography, and I am interested in overriding the default max-width 65ch limit on each line.

The default setting was `max-w-prose`, and I have tried setting `max-w-none` to the parent element, along with `prose`, but it doesn't seem to work (although it messes with the alignment). I have also tried setting the `max-w-none` with `prose` in every element (wary of unwanted overrides to 65ch) but this also isn't cutting it.

I am thinking this could be done via the tailwind.config.js file, like:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            'prose': {
              'max-width': '100ch'
            },
            'max-w-prose': {
              'max-width': '100ch'
            },
        ...
```

but I can't figure it out. Any tips are super welcome!

Comment: As mentioned in the tailwind documentation: [overriding max width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#overriding-max-width), setting `max-w-none` on the parent element next to `prose` is the way to go. But I wonder whether you wanted to unset the 65 character limit or you wanted to override it with the new setting of 100 character limit. I came across the same problem and I just wanted to unset the 65 character limit, so I added `max-w-none` next to my `prose` class and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is default `.prose` CSS properties so typography config should be like this

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            maxWidth: '100ch', // add required value here
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7BScXdNoOm?file=config)

Comment: Tailwind has documentation for updating max width, this is the recommended solution: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#overriding-max-width

Comment: Setting it in your Tailwind config would be easier for overriding it for every use of `prose`.